# Visual Studio C++, how to change the text color for "nullptr"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

It's distracting to me to see keywords like class, for, while in bright blue, but also to have nullptr in bright blue. It draws attention to the word "nullptr". Is there any way to override VS's coloring for just this word?

Right now I am using #define null nullptr , which is a workaround at least for my own code.

Comment: It is a keyword in the C++/CLI and C++11 languages.  So it gets the same color as "class", another keyword.  There ought to be a programmer nearby that is going to *really* hate on that #define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't allow you override keyword coloring feature. There is no direct way!
However, It is possible by writing your own Syntax Colorizing plugin.

Find more information here: 
[Syntax Colorizing (Managed Package Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165041.aspx)

You can filter `nullptr` keyword in `ScanTokenAndProvideInfoAboutIt`() function.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer, wish it were simpler. Back to the SciTE code editor which is so much easier to customize.